# Как написать корзину для интернет-магазина на php?

Tags: php

Как написать корзину на php? Желательно код с комментариями, или ссылку на сайт, где это все подробно описывается. Весь интернет обшарил, но нигде не нашёл.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант-вполне работоспособный и реализуем новичком:
Используйте ajax для добавления товара в корзину. Все товары сохраняйте в текущей сессии, не думаю что там будут мегабайты из огромных списков с продукцией, поэтому базу пока отметаем или будем использовать в самом конце при покупке.
ajax: Надо науйчить его отправлять только идентификатор товара (если такой имеется) и предусмотреть обновление циферки (это уже js) возле иконки на корзине.
php: не забывать вытаскивать из сессии кол-во товаров и отображать возле корзинки. Также увеличивать список. Создать страничку корзины и заказа товара (конечная форма заявки). Написать код на php для записи товара в базу, где товаровед увидит заказ.
Попробую что-то вменяемое прямо тут написать (без тестов, но суть думаю станет ясна):
ajax:

```
javascript:
function addToCorzin(_idTovara){
    var s=document.createElement('script');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    s.src='http://urlsite/ajaxAddToCorzina.php?id='+_id+'&_sys='+new Date().getTime();
}

php(ajaxAddToCorzina.php):
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['id']))
    if(isset($_SESSION['tovars']))
        array_push($_SESSION['tovars'],$_GET['id']); 
    else $_SESSION['tovars']=array($_GET['id']);
print 'document.getElementById(\'corzinaCountTovarsLabel\').innerHTML='.count($_SESSION['tovars']).';';

php(рисуем корзинку где-нибудь - привожу с html):
<div class="corzina">
Товаров:<span id="corzinaCountTovarsLabel"><?=isset($_SESSION['tovars'])?count($_SESSION['tovars']):0;?></span>
...
</div>

html(заказ товара):
<div class="tovarClass">
<img src="tovar1url"/><input type="button" onclick="addToCorzin(<?=$fromBDData['id'];?>)"/>
</div>
```

Дальше теория:
На странице оформления заказа выводите список товаров (надеюсь понятно откуда брать идентификаторы товаров), затем выводите поля для формы. Теперь что с базой делать или нет и какие плюсы и минусы: Если делать в базу то необходимо по крайне мере пару таблиц (одна для реквизитов заказывающего товар, а другая-это ассоциация с вашими товарами и текущих параметров заказчика). Данный подход вынудит делать в админке окно с просмотром заказов. Как сделать по другому:-без базы данных. Все что назаказывали и все что ввел про себя покупатель отсылать на почту.

P.S.: Как только я решился написать эту муть) Данный функционал можно реализовать за один день даже новичку. Думаю на первых порах подойдет. Почему сложного делать не нужно, так это потому, как у Вас нет платежей через сайт, там сложнее и этот подход вам не подойдет.

Comment: addToCorzin... 

    killCodeAuthorKotoriyTakPishetKod();

Answer (score 0):

Хм... А какие именно функции корзины вам нужны и что именно не получается?
Подозреваю, что хорошую и удобную корзину на одном лишь php написать невозможно, необходимо использовать AJAX.
Если эта технология вам не известна, посмотрите объект JsHttpRequest на [сайте Дмитрия Котерова](http://dklab.ru/). Он может существенно облегчить вам жизнь, особенно если использовать совместно с библиотекой jQuery.
Но и JsHttpRequest, и jQuery имеют в своей основе JavaScript.